# Hough Transform: improving algorithm efficiency over OpenCL

Tags: c, opencl, transform, detection, geometry

I am trying to detect a circle in binary image using hough transform.

When I use Opencv's built-in function for the circular hough transform, it is OK and I can find the circle.

Now I try to write my own 'kernel' code for doing hough transform but is very very slow:

```
 kernel void hough_circle(read_only image2d_t imageIn, global int* in,const int w_hough,__global int * circle)
 {
     sampler_t sampler=CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE | CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE | CLK_FILTER_NEAREST;
     int gid0 = get_global_id(0);
     int gid1 = get_global_id(1);
     uint4 pixel;
     int x0=0,y0=0,r;
     int maxval=0;
     pixel=read_imageui(imageIn,sampler,(int2)(gid0,gid1));
     if(pixel.x==255)
     {
     for(int r=20;r<150;r+=2)
     {
    // int r=100;

              for(int theta=0; theta<360;theta+=2)
              {

                              x0=(int) round(gid0-r*cos( (float) radians( (float) theta) ));
                            y0=(int) round(gid1-r*sin( (float) radians( (float) theta) ));
                           if((x0>0) && (x0<get_global_size(0)) && (y0>0)&&(y0<get_global_size(1)))
                            atom_inc(&in[w_hough*y0+x0]);
              }
              if(maxval<in[w_hough*y0+x0])
              {
              maxval=in[w_hough*y0+x0];
                circle[0]=gid0;
                circle[1]=gid1;
                circle[2]=r;
              }

              }

     }

 }
```

There are source codes for the hough opencl library with opencv, but its hard to me for extract a specific function that helps me.

Can anyone offer a better source code example, or help me understand why this is so inefficient?
the code main.cpp and kernel.cl compress in rar file http://www.files.com/set/527152684017e 
use opencv lib for read and display image >

Comment: Please add links to existing source codes, such as the OpenCL library or others.  Please also give your benchmarks, so that people can understand what work you've done already.

Answer (score 1):

Making repeated calls to `sin()` and `cos()` is computationally expensive. Since you only ever call these functions with the same 180 values of `theta`, you could speed things up by precalculating these values and storing them in an array.

A more robust approach would be to use the [midpoint circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) to find the perimeters of these circles by simple integer arithmetic.

Comment: thank you for help me . the sin and cos replace with array  __constant float sin_parameter[360]={0.00000,0.01745,0.03490,.....} and also another one for cos but the execution is also slow .
i use opencv default function to draw circle put parameter of center and radius cvcircle

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is running a huge CPU block of code in only 1 workitem, the results as expected, is a slowww kernel.

Detailed answer:
The only place were you use the work-item ID is just for the pixel value, if that condition is met then you run a big chunck of code. Some of the work-items will trigger this some of them don't. The ones that trigger it will make indirectly all the work group to run that code, and this will slow you down.

In addition, the workitems that don't enter that condition will be idle. Depending on the image maybe 99% of them are idle.

I would rewrite your algorithm to use 1 workgroup per pixel. 
If the condition is met the workgroup will run the algorithm, if it is not, the whole workgroup will skip. And in the case the workgroup enters the condition, you will have many workitems to play with. This will allow a redesign of the code such that the inner for loops run in parallel.

Comment: thank you . iam new in opencl,in the main program define global_group_size and local_group_size the global equal to the size dimention of image and local=8 .the kernel code is run on all workitem item ??? how can know that ?? if it run only one work item and the others idle the utlization not reach 99% .
is that any hint of code to optimize the kernal 
thank you again .soory for my bad english
the code is here main.cpp and kernel in rar file http://www.files.com/set/527152684017e
sorry for my bad english