# opencl local array within kernel

Tags: arrays, kernel, opencl, local

I am trying to detect a circle in binary image using hough transform. 
and post my problem here [Hough Transform: improving algorithm efficiency over OpenCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667582/hough-transform-improving-algorithm-efficiency-over-opencl)

the kernel code is very slow when execute . the wait time in atomic function and i try to use local memory for that is faster but the problem in output accumulator in[]
the kernel code

```
   kernel void hough_circle(read_only image2d_t imageIn, global int* in,const int w_hough,__global int * circle)
  {
         sampler_t sampler=CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE | CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE | CLK_FILTER_NEAREST;
     int gid0 = get_global_id(0);
     int gid1 = get_global_id(1);
         const int nWidth = get_local_size(0);

int i = get_group_id(0);
int j = get_group_id(1); 
int idX = get_local_id(0);
int idY = get_local_id(1);
    int ii = i*nWidth + idX; 
int jj = j*nWidth + idY; 
     uint4 pixel;
     int x0=0,y0=0,r;
     int maxval=0;
        local int localImage[25];
        localImage[idY*5+idX] = 0;   
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
     pixel=read_imageui(imageIn,sampler,(int2)(gid0,gid1));
     if(pixel.x==255)
     {
    //  #pragma unroll 20
        for(int r=90;r<110;r+=1)
     {
         // int r=190;

            //    #pragma unroll 360
               for(int theta=0; theta<360;theta++)
              {

                          //     x0=(int) round(gid0-r*cos( (float) radians( (float) theta) ));
                          //    y0=(int) round(gid1-r*sin( (float) radians( (float) theta) ));

                              x0=(int) round(gid0-r*sin_parameter[theta] );
                            y0=(int) round(gid1-r*cos_parameter[theta] );
                                  if((x0>0) && (x0<get_global_size(0)) && (y0>0)&&(y0<get_global_size(1)))
                             //  in[w_hough*y0+x0]++;
                                   localImage[5*y0+x0]++;
                            //  atom_inc(&in[w_hough*y0+x0]);
               }
              }

     }


 in[jj*w_hough+ii]=  localImage[jj*5+ii];

  }
```

the local 
the problem in output accumulator in[] show incorrect value random 
can any one help me what change i do to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Local memory is shared across the workgroup, so I guess the first question is how are you splitting up your threads into workgroups?

If you are just using the default values in `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`, your are letting OpenCL decide which thread has access to local memory and seemingly odd things will happen.

Perhaps you meant to use `private` memory instead?  If so, remove local before the declaration of localImage.  Local memory is declared similarly to global:

`__kernel void function(__global float *Input, __local float *WorkgroupBuffer){ }`

Comment: i am new in opencl ,did you mean about local work size and global work size

Comment: size_t szGlobalWorkSize[2]={img.cols,img.rows};
 size_t szLocalWorkSize[2]={16,16};

Comment: clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(clCommandQueue,hough_circle,2,NULL,szGlobalWorkSize,szLocalWorkSize,0,NULL,&event);

Comment: img.cols=img.rows=512;
i will try  about declaration of local memory
the code main.cpp and kernel.cl compress in rar file http://www.files.com/set/527152684017e use opencv lib for read and display img